# Filter lookup field by date

Tags: sharepoint-addin, custom-list, lookup-column

I have two lists. First list is a list of courses with title and date. Second list is a registration list with name and lookup by course title. Is there a way to filter the lookup so that it only display courses that are not over yet?

I tried using a calculated field of `IF(Date>TODAY(), Course, " ")` but it would filter out the already added items in the lookup to blanks once it has passed and that's not what I want. I just want the dropdown to be filtered and if a registration has already been submitted, then it doesn't disappear.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of empty space use blank. Lookup will not display blank values

```
IF(Date>TODAY(), Course, "")
```

Comment: I tried that but it still gives a blank in the lookup if the item is past today's date.